# SQL Server Express with Advanced Services (with Reporting Services)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, configuration

I have tried to download SQL Server 2005 Express edition about 4 times trying to find the correct version that has business intelligence studio and reporting services in it?

Every time I try to unhide the advanced configuration during install, it's never there...

Can anyone point me to the correct download?

Looking for 2005 (not 2008) because my work SQL server that I am trying to learn this for is 2005, and the training material I have is for 2005 and VS 2008 does not want to integrate with SQL2008 express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sorry if you saw my first answer, I misread your question as Integration Services...]

Reporting Services is available with SQL Express with Advanced Services.  The Business Intelligence tools are available in the SQL Express Toolkit.

Both are available from the same location.  Here is the link to the [**download page**](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express-down.aspx).

Comment: thanks very much. i think my hang up with reporting services may be due to an error I am getting when sql server install scans my computer's config and finds that I do not have IIS installed or it is not enabled. would this be something that comes with sql server anyway?? how would i enable it if i do have it? where do i find IIS in the control panel. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's probably your problem.  Reporting services relies on IIS.   IIS doesn't come with SQL.  You have to install it separately, but it is available for any version of Windows (workstation or server editions).  What are you running SQL Express on?  You have to add it via Windows Components, which you get to differently depending on what version of Windows you have.

Comment: I am running all above on my home computer, just because I am trying to learn as much as I can about it all ASAP, since my work just made me the unpofficial DBA until they get someone. So I am enjoying this actually. Windows Vista.

Comment: know where I can find that?? thanks for your help SQUILLMAN! much appreciated!

Comment: No problem!  Here's a link for a good looking tutorial on installing IIS on Vista: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/install-iis-7-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/

Comment: no that is still not fixing my dilema....thanks though. learned something new.

Comment: In what since?  Can't install IIS, or Reporting Svcs still whacked?

Comment: sorry. yeah apparently i already have IIS on my computer, though I think its the IIS 6, not 7....I assume that does not matter. When I install (keep trying to reinstall) SQL Server 2005 express w/AS SP3, there is a check box for hiding advanced configuration options. i think i have to do this so on the next screen i can install the reporting services and report manager. otherwise this install won't put it in

Comment: so when the install scans my computers config just prior to this, i get the little hyperlick message right beside the IIS, and clicking gives me "IIS is either not install, or not enabled"...which it is definately installed, and I check every box in the drill down tree struc just to make sure....

so???? i dunno man!

Comment: Have you confirmed that IIS is indeed running?  BTW- It's IIS7.  IIS6 was for WinXP / Win2003.

Comment: not sure i can confirm that its running? well I just thought it was 6 because a couple of the selection said "such & such 6". what about server editions like server2003, would that be IIS6, or a totally different ball of wax. thanks!

Comment: In the Services control panel make sure the World Wide Web Publishing Services is started.  IIS6 = WinXP/2003, IIS7.x = Vista/Win7/2008.